# Error creating my first Mock object

Tags: c#, nunit, nmock

I'm new to this, so doubtlessly I'm doing something silly.

I am trying to create a mock object:

```
mockCurrencyConversion = mocks.NewMock<ICurrencyConversion>();
```

and getting this error:

> **The non-generic method 'NMock2.Mockery.NewMock(System.Type)' cannot be
>   used with type arguments**

**ICurrencyConversion:**

```
public interface ICurrencyConversion
{
    decimal convertCurrency(string fromCurrency, string toCurrency, decimal amount);

    int addNumbers(int i, int j);

    decimal getRate(CurrencyRateResponse rates, string fromCurrency);

    CurrencyRateResponse getCurrencyRates();

    HttpWebRequest GetWebRequest(string formattedUri);
}
```

**My Test Code:**

```
[TestFixture]
public class WhygoTest
{
    private Mockery mocks;
    private ICurrencyConversion mockCurrencyConversion;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        mocks = new Mockery();
        mockCurrencyConversion = mocks.NewMock<ICurrencyConversion>();

    }

    [Test]
    public void MyAddTest()
    {
        var cc = new CurrencyConversion();

        Assert.AreEqual(cc.addNumbers(1, 2), 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error seems quite clear to me! It says you can't pass type arguments to that method, and that instead it takes a parameter of type `System.Type`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `NewMock()` method with the type as an argument:

```
mockCurrencyConversion = 
    (ICurrencyConversion) mocks.NewMock(typeof(ICurrencyConversion));
```

Comment: thanks for this, I now get an error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'ICurrencyConversion'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You can explicitly cast to `ICurrencyConversion` using the updated code in my answer.